Is there any more information about Hillis' mathematical discovery that is referred in this video clip?
There is a video segment of an interview of Daniel Hillis where he talks about a mathematical discovery that he made while he was an undergraduate student at MIT which his math professor initially dismissed.

Is there any more information about Hillis mathematical discovery that
is referred in this video clip?


It sounds like an elementary identity involving multiset coefficients that surprised Rota, there seems to be no record of specifics. The only way to find out might be to ask Hillis directly.

@Conifold I was actually hoping that someone with academic or scientific historian credentials would ask him.
